# Domain based redirect in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I have an .htaccess file that is shared between a number of websites. Each of these sites are served from the same set of files but load a different configuration based on the domain name they run on.

However, I need to add a number of 301 redirects and I'm running into a small problem. I only want the redirects to execute for a specific domain, not for each of the domains the .htaccess is used by. E.g. I want to redirect `mysite1.com/some/path` to redirect to `mysite2.com/some/other/path` but the problem is that if `/some/path` also exists for `mysite3.com` it's also redirected.

What I basically need is something like:

```
<if host = mysite1.com>
  Redirect /some/path http://mysite2/some/other/path
</if>
```

Is this possible in .htaccess?

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633400/configuring-proxypass-on-htaccess-to-show-tomcat-through-apache-http-server]

Answer (score 2):

**It is possible**, by adding a condition to your RewriteRule eg.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.othersite1.com$   [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.othersite2.com$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^some/path        http://mysite2/some/other/path [R]
```

**What this does is:**

- Then it tests if the URL requested matches "some/path". Remember that in a .htaccess context the URLs are relative to the directory your .htaccess file is in. If this matches the conditions above it are avaluated.
- Since the two conditions are OR-ed together, only one needs to match. In this example I have two domains I want this rule to redirect for. You can easily add more.
- Finally the URL is rewritten, and redirected...